# Calculate $(\frac{3}{11})$ in the following ways....

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-reciprocity

Evaluate $(\frac{3}{11})$

- Currently going through a study set on a Quadratic Reciprocity, I have to evaluate $(\frac{3}{11})$ in the following three ways:

(1) Computing the squares modulo 11

(2) Euler's Criterion

(3) Gauss' Lemma

I have part 3 figured out but having trouble with the first two any help is appreciated.

- I assume for (1) I would calculate every square mod 11?
- As for (2) and (3) I am quite lost, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) yes that's what you do.  (2) do you know what Euler's criterion says?

Comment: [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) directs us to compute $3^5\pmod {11}$.  Not too difficult.  Neither is [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(number_theory))